# Can I power an air pump motor with an L298N motor driver?

Tags: arduino, motor, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am trying to control a [mini pump motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FHAEFD6).  All the tutorials I have seen mention using a relay but I do not have one. I do, however, have an L298N motor driver. If I'm not mistaken, the pump motor operates similarly to a DC motor so I thought I might be able to run it from the motor driver, like I would with a 6VDC motor. I would use the motor driver with an Arduino board, by the way. Would that work?

Comment: l298 drops about 2 V, so not ideal. A FET-based driver might be better. May still work though, if it's all you have.

Comment: L298 is double full-bridge driver, it is made for changing polarity of two loads and using it for single motor is redundancy. This pump pumps in one side independent on polarity. One transistor (either MOS or bipolar), flyback diode and resistor (gate or base) will be enough.

Comment: It should work. L298 is used to change the direction of current thus changing the direction of the rotation. Also you are able to control the speed of the motor using the module.